# Tkinter widget is not updating based on inputs?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a widget in python using tkinter library. It has one combobox

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import * 
import os
import time
import win32api

def f_step():
    window=Tk()
    style = Style() 
    style.configure('W.TButton', font =
               ('calibri', 12, 'bold'), 
                foreground = 'blue') 
    
    s = Style()                     # Creating style element
    s.configure('Wild.TRadiobutton',    # First argument is the name of style. Needs to end with: .TRadiobutton
        background='bisque2',         # Setting background to our specified color above
        font = "calibri 10 bold")         # You can define colors like this also
    
    window.title('Tool tool')
    window.geometry("700x300+10+10")
    #window.geometry(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)


    txt_1=StringVar()
    lbl_1 = Label(window,text="Are result files same", background ="bisque2",font = "calibri 10 bold").place(x=10,y=40)
    lbl_2 = ttk.Combobox(window,textvariable = txt_1, values = ["Yes","No"], background ="bisque2",font = "calibri 10 bold").place(x=275,y=40)
    a1 = txt_1.get()
    
    if a1 == "Yes":
        txt_2=StringVar()
        lbl_3 = Label(window,text="Working directory path", background ="bisque2",font = "calibri 10 bold").place(x=10,y=70)
        txt_b = Entry(window,textvariable=txt_2,width=60).place(x=275,y=70)
        txt_3=StringVar()
        lbl_4 = Label(window,text="file name (without extenstion)", background ="bisque2",font = "calibri 10 bold").place(x=10,y=100)
        txt_c = Entry(window,textvariable=txt_2,width=60).place(x=275,y=100)  
    elif a1 == "No":
        txt_2=StringVar()
        lbl_3 = Label(window,text="Working directory path", background ="bisque2",font = "calibri 10 bold").place(x=10,y=70)
        txt_b = Entry(window,textvariable=txt_2,width=60).place(x=275,y=70)
        txt_3=StringVar()
        lbl_4 = Label(window,text="file1 name (without extenstion)", background ="bisque2",font = "calibri 10 bold").place(x=10,y=100)
        txt_c = Entry(window,textvariable=txt_2,width=60).place(x=275,y=100)  
        txt_4=StringVar()
        lbl_5 = Label(window,text="file2 name (without extenstion)", background ="bisque2",font = "calibri 10 bold").place(x=10,y=130)
        txt_d = Entry(window,textvariable=txt_2,width=60).place(x=275,y=130)  
       
    btn_1 = Button(window, text="run",style = 'W.TButton',command=clicked)
    btn_1.place(x=300,y=250)
    window.configure(bg='bisque2')
    window.resizable(0, 0)
    window.mainloop()
    
def clicked():
    a=1212
f_step()
```

It has combobox but once i select one option (yes or no) it does not update the following options. Please help me to solve this as i am not sure how to update the application based on real time inputs. i do not want it to updated once i click the button. Also this is just the portion of code which i am having the problem please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind the virtual event `<<ComboboxSelected>>` to a callback and show the required labels and entries based on the combobox selection in the callback:

```py
def f_step():
    window = Tk()
    window.title('Tool tool')
    window.geometry("700x300+10+10")
    #window.geometry(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
    window.configure(bg='bisque2')
    window.resizable(0, 0)
    
    s = ttk.Style()                       # Creating style element
    s.configure('W.TButton', font=('calibri', 12, 'bold'), foreground='blue') 
    s.configure('Wild.TRadiobutton',    # First argument is the name of style. Needs to end with: .TRadiobutton
                background='bisque2',   # Setting background to our specified color above
                font="calibri 10 bold") # You can define colors like this also

    def on_change(event):
        # show the labels and entries
        lbl_3.place(x=10, y=70)
        txt_b.place(x=275, y=70)

        lbl_4.place(x=10, y=100)
        txt_c.place(x=275, y=100)  

        a1 = txt_1.get()
        if a1 == "Yes":
            lbl_5.place_forget()
            txt_d.place_forget()
        else:
            lbl_5.place(x=10, y=130)
            txt_d.place(x=275, y=130)  

    txt_1 = StringVar()
    Label(window, text="Are result files same", background ="bisque2", font="calibri 10 bold").place(x=10,y=40)
    cb_1 = ttk.Combobox(window, textvariable=txt_1, values=["Yes","No"], background="bisque2", font="calibri 10 bold", state="readonly")
    cb_1.place(x=275,y=40)
    cb_1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", on_change)

    # define the labels and entries and initially they are hidden
    txt_2 = StringVar()
    lbl_3 = Label(window, text="Working directory path", background="bisque2", font="calibri 10 bold")
    txt_b = Entry(window, textvariable=txt_2, width=60)
    txt_3 = StringVar()
    lbl_4 = Label(window, text="file1 name (without extenstion)", background="bisque2", font="calibri 10 bold")
    txt_c = Entry(window, textvariable=txt_3, width=60)
    txt_4 = StringVar()
    lbl_5 = Label(window, text="file2 name (without extenstion)", background="bisque2", font="calibri 10 bold")
    txt_d = Entry(window, textvariable=txt_4, width=60)
       
    btn_1 = ttk.Button(window, text="run", style='W.TButton', command=clicked)
    btn_1.place(x=300, y=250)

    window.mainloop()
```

---

*Note that your code uses `txt_2` variable in `txt_c` and `txt_d` entries and I think it is typo and fix it.*

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is `lbl_2.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", f_step)` also note that you must add a parameter in the `f_step` function as it is passed form combo virtual event. This will make sure to update whenever the option is changed

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

import os
import time
import win32api

def f_step(event=None):
    a1 = txt_1.get()
    if a1 == "Yes":
        txt_2=StringVar()
        lbl_3 = Label(window,text="Working directory path", background ="bisque2",font = "calibri 10 bold").place(x=10,y=70)
        txt_b = Entry(window,textvariable=txt_2,width=60).place(x=275,y=70)
        txt_3=StringVar()

        lbl_4 = Label(window,text="file name (without extenstion)", background ="bisque2",font = "calibri 10 bold").place(x=10,y=100)
        txt_c = Entry(window,textvariable=txt_2,width=60).place(x=275,y=100)  
        
    elif a1 == "No":
        txt_2=StringVar()
        lbl_3 = Label(window,text="Working directory path", background ="bisque2",font = "calibri 10 bold").place(x=10,y=70)
        txt_b = Entry(window,textvariable=txt_2,width=60).place(x=275,y=70)
        txt_3=StringVar()

        lbl_4 = Label(window,text="file1 name (without extenstion)", background ="bisque2",font = "calibri 10 bold").place(x=10,y=100)
        txt_c = Entry(window,textvariable=txt_2,width=60).place(x=275,y=100)  

        txt_4=StringVar()
        lbl_5 = Label(window,text="file2 name (without extenstion)", background ="bisque2",font = "calibri 10 bold").place(x=10,y=130)
        txt_d = Entry(window,textvariable=txt_2,width=60).place(x=275,y=130)  
       
    
    
def clicked():
    a=1212
    #f_step()

window=Tk()
style = Style() 
style.configure('W.TButton', font =
               ('calibri', 12, 'bold'), 
                foreground = 'blue') 
    
s = Style()                     # Creating style element
s.configure('Wild.TRadiobutton',    # First argument is the name of style. Needs to end with: .TRadiobutton
        background='bisque2',         # Setting background to our specified color above
        font = "calibri 10 bold")         # You can define colors like this also
    
window.title('Tool tool')
window.geometry("700x300+10+10")
    #window.geometry(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)


txt_1=StringVar()
lbl_1 = Label(window,text="Are result files same", background ="bisque2",font = "calibri 10 bold").place(x=10,y=40)
lbl_2 = Combobox(window,textvariable = txt_1, values = ["Yes","No"], background ="bisque2",font = "calibri 10 bold")
lbl_2.place(x=275,y=40)
#lbl_2.current(1)
lbl_2.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", f_step)


btn_1 = Button(window, text="run",style = 'W.TButton',command=clicked)
btn_1.place(x=300,y=250)


window.configure(bg='bisque2')
window.resizable(0, 0)
window.mainloop()
```

also if you want to update only when run is clicked you may call the `f_step` from `clicked()` and remove the binding from combobox.

ok as per your request here is the Updated code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

import os
import time
import win32api

def f_step(event=None):

    global lbl_3
    global txt_b
    global lbl_4
    global lbl_c
    global lbl_5
    global txt_d
    
    hide()
    
    a1 = txt_1.get()
    
    txt_2=StringVar()
    txt_3=StringVar()

    lbl_3 = Label(window,text="Working directory path", background ="bisque2",font = "calibri 10 bold")
    lbl_3.place(x=10,y=70)

    txt_b = Entry(window,textvariable=txt_2,width=60)
    txt_b.place(x=275,y=70)

    txt_b = Entry(window,textvariable=txt_2,width=60)
    txt_b.place(x=275,y=70)
    
    lbl_4 = Label(window,text="file name (without extenstion)", background ="bisque2",font = "calibri 10 bold")
    lbl_4.place(x=10,y=100)

    txt_c = Entry(window,textvariable=txt_2,width=60)
    txt_c.place(x=275,y=100)
    
        
    if a1 == "No":
        lbl_5 = Label(window,text="file2 name (without extenstion)", background ="bisque2",font = "calibri 10 bold")
        lbl_5.place(x=10,y=130)

        txt_d = Entry(window,textvariable=txt_2,width=60)
        txt_d.place(x=275,y=130)  

def hide():
    #lbl_3.place_forget()
    
    lbl_3.destroy()
    txt_b.destroy()

    
    
    lbl_4.destroy()
    txt_c.destroy()

    lbl_5.destroy()
    txt_d.destroy()

            
    
def clicked():
    a=1212
    f_step()


window=Tk()

style = Style() 
style.configure('W.TButton', font =
               ('calibri', 12, 'bold'), 
                foreground = 'blue') 
    
s = Style()                     # Creating style element
s.configure('Wild.TRadiobutton',    # First argument is the name of style. Needs to end with: .TRadiobutton
        background='bisque2',         # Setting background to our specified color above
        font = "calibri 10 bold")         # You can define colors like this also
    
window.title('Tool tool')
window.geometry("700x300+10+10")


lbl_3 = Label(window)
txt_b = Entry(window)

txt_b = Entry(window)

    
lbl_4 = Label(window)
txt_c = Entry(window)

lbl_5 = Label(window)
txt_d = Entry(window)


txt_1=StringVar()
lbl_1 = Label(window,text="Are result files same", background ="bisque2",font = "calibri 10 bold").place(x=10,y=40)
lbl_2 = Combobox(window,textvariable = txt_1, values = ["Yes","No"], background ="bisque2",font = "calibri 10 bold")
lbl_2.place(x=275,y=40)
#lbl_2.current(1)
lbl_2.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", f_step)


btn_1 = Button(window, text="run",style = 'W.TButton',command=clicked)
btn_1.place(x=300,y=250)


window.configure(bg='bisque2')
window.resizable(0, 0)
window.mainloop()
```

you can use the `widget.destroy()` to delete the widget whole together or `widget.place_forget` to temporarily hide the widget. Note: if you use `widget.place_forget` you don't need to recreate the widget instead change the existing widget using `widget.config`

Comment: Thank you JacksonPro, it is working almost. Now when i select "yes or no", it gives me required outputs, but the problem is suppose i am changing my option from NO to YES it is not updating the output(for my case it should delete the "file2 name input entry"). I will be needing this modification such a way that whole widget (other part of tool, which is not shown in given code) should adjust automatically once options are changed.